# Excel VBA Adding 1 hour to a date / time string

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I have a text string that looks like this: "06/10/15 4:53pm".  I want to add 1 hour (60 minutes exactly) to the text string looks like this:  "06/10/15 5:53pm"

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert it to a date, add an hour, and convert back to string using format

```
Private Sub TestIt()

    MsgBox AddHour("06/10/15 4:53pm")

End Sub

Public Function AddHour(ByVal sTime As String) As String
    Dim dt As Date

    dt = CDate(sTime)
    dt = DateAdd("h", 1, dt)

    AddHour = Format(dt, "mm/dd/yy h:nnam/pm")

End Function
```

Reference:

- [VBA CDate Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)
- [VBA DateAdd Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function)
- [VBA Format Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx)

Comment: `DateAdd()` is slow and unnecessary for something as simple as adding hours to a date. My answer (on this page) is more than twice as fast to execute. It's also MUCH more concise.

Comment: @ExcelHero Here are my thoughts on why my answer has been upvoted and accepted. If someone must ask how to add an hour to a date string in vba, they should get an answer which is easy to replicate and understand in vba. My answer uses sound, built-in functions for doing what the OP asked in vba. Yours is mostly a math equation, which is a shortcut. My answer explains the need for conversion in the opening line. That's what someone needs to understand if they have this question. You are optimizing the solution but missing the point of the question. No optimization is need. This is a spreadsheet

Comment: Appreciate your comment, but I've made a 30-year career optimizing spreadsheets. Your notion is EXTREMELY WRONG. Your answer is OK. It is not great.

Comment: @ExcelHero -- I concede YOU ARE RIGHT about optimization, especially having made a 30 year career of it. I respect that. I was pointing out the question was not about optimization. It was about converting data types. My answer is clear because it addressed the core issue -- understanding. Your answer is optimized for speed and brevity, but not for understanding. You may feel entitled to votes because your answer is short and fast, but those are not people's only concerns. Understanding is paramount. I've made a career of optimizing understanding. Clarity was the appropriate response here.

Comment: Once a user realizes what `1 / 24` means, they immediately become a much more effective Excel user... and not only on the VBA side. I teach advanced Excel... formulas and VBA. `DateAdd()` has it's uses, but understanding my answer (which does not take much thought) gets a user further down the path to being an effective spreadsheet modeler.

Comment: @ExcelHero I agree. I would be happy to upvote your answer if it included a few things: 1) Some explanatory text regarding the need for conversions from string to date and date to string, 2) Something about dates supporting math where 1 = a day, and 3) a solution for getting the string back in the original format (which the OP asked for). Your suggestions would definitely improve my answer if I incorporated them. I would be happy to include these in mine if you do not want to include them in yours.

Answer (score 2):

No VBA needed...assuming the time value above(06/10/15 4:53pm) is in cell A1 the Formula you are looking for is:

```
=A1+TIME(1,0,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a VBA solution:

```
s = "06/10/15 4:53pm"

MsgBox CDate(s) + 1 / 24
```

Answer (score -1):

For operations with date and time in VBA is DateAdd function. You can find how to use it in this link: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php