# Excel VBA Convert String Date to a real date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm using the following code but for some reason the second line isn't converting it into a real date.

```
DateStr = Replace(DateStr, "-", "/")
DateStr = Format(CDate(DateStr), "dd/mm/yyyy")
DateStr = DateStr + 1
```

Even if I do:

```
Dim RealDate As Date

DateStr = Replace(DateStr, "-", "/")
RealDate = Format(CDate(DateStr), "dd/mm/yyyy")
RealDate = RealDate + 1
```

As you can see from line 3, I am trying to +1 to the day which could also change the month or year potentially.

Comment: What does your input string look like, and what's your default date format?

Comment: `Format()` returns a String only if you haven't noticed. It should only be used to display data, not converting.

Comment: @TimWilliams `21/07/2015` exactly how my date is laid out in the UK

Comment: You might find this helpful. It's version of what Jeeped is doing, just more broken down so you can follow the logic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439282/excel-vba-adding-1-hour-to-a-date-time-string/31439538#31439538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having trouble identifying just where you should be adding 1 to the date. Try,

```
DateStr = Format(CDate(DateStr) + 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

The [CDate conversion function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/2dt118h2(v=vs.84).aspx) is where you get the numerical date vaue that will accept the addition of another day.

Answer (score 1):

Second one works OK for me:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim RealDate As Date, DateStr As String

    DateStr = "7-20-2015"

    DateStr = Replace(DateStr, "-", "/")
    RealDate = Format(CDate(DateStr), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    RealDate = RealDate + 1

    Debug.Print RealDate '>> 7/21/2015

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps, but relying on VBA overhead to convert a String into a Date shouldn't be recommended practise.

Comment: You should drop the format -- it's misleading. Variable RealDate is a date and Format returns string so it is superfluous.

Comment: I only posted this to demonstrate that the OP's code did seem to work, not to suggest that it was a good approach...